# Is it possible to direct all audio output, including music output, to a Bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth, music, bluetooth-audio, headset, bluetooth-hsp

I am able to make and receive calls from my Samsung ACE S5830 phone using a  Bluetooth device. However, when I play MP3 songs on my phone, the output does not play through the Bluetooth mono headset; it just directly plays from the phone's speakers.

Is there a way to direct all audio output to the Bluetooth mono headset?

Answer (score 16):

I did some googling and stumbled across [this post on androidforums.com](http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid/16849-audio-other-than-calls-bluetooth-headset.html) which has some suggestions:

1. There are several apps which appear to provide this functionality.  [BTmono](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono) is the only free one I found that isn't limited to a certain length of time.  It requires Android 2.2+.  There are several other similar apps that you can also see at that link.
2. [This person](http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid/16849-audio-other-than-calls-bluetooth-headset.html#post122894) posted a trick which looks like it works without the use of an additional app:

> 1. I went to the phone and dialed '**' (2 stars) which creates a 'p' for pause. Then press call. This enables the headset without actually
>      placing a call.
> 2. After this I started doggcatcher (or other audio / video player) and it played through the headset. Everything went through the headset
>      after this point.
> 3. In order to stop playback to my headset I just called my voicemail and hung up. At that point, audio was routed back to the speaker.
>
> EDIT: I have found that it only works when my ringer volume is off or
>   on vibrate. Also, the media volume needs to be turned up separately --
>   Either from the settings control or prior to performing the 'p' call.
>   The volume rocker only controls the Bluetooth call volume after the
>   bluetooth headset is active.

Comment: BTmono works perfect! Samsung galaxy note 3.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, audio apps use the media channel, which will be played over Bluetooth if your Bluetooth device supports that A2DP profile.

Check the specs on your headset to see if it supports A2DP -- if it does, please edit your question to include additional information on the music app you use and the make and model of your headset.

Answer (score 4):

If

1. You want to hear music on your bluetooth device
2. Your bluetooth device pairs perfectly with your android phone.
3. It works only with calls, media still plays on your device speakers.

BTMono is a great tool that suits your requirement. It will allow you to simply turn ON media streaming and you are good to go.

Remember that it is free and you need to restart the app after every phone call.
This feature can be unlocked in the pro version which is just $1 :D

Answer (score 3):

Try [Mono Bluetooth Router](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.monobluetoothfree&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd). Its free version has more feautures than BTMono.

Comment: +1. I installed the free version, and it works fine for me.  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S Relay.  This is a cellphone which is probably somewhat similar to a Samsung Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try my application to direct non-call audio to BT. Here's is my github link: https://github.com/sauravpradhan/AnySound2BT

Comment: It didn't work for me. I think it crashed. I have posted slightly more information [here](https://github.com/sauravpradhan/AnySound2BT/issues/1). Unfortunately, I haven't provided a backtrace, and a backtrace is probably what you'd need in order to fix the problem.

Comment: The crash might be because I'm not releasing the resource , the code works perfectly in most of the phones if tried according to the steps mentioned in Github!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw it out there for anyone wanting to know that [BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono) worked like a charm for my HTC Desire S with android 2.3.3 and my Plantronics Explorer 210! Extremely easy interface for BTmono too.

Answer (score 0):

I used [BTmono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bedoig.BTmono&hl=en) so I could use a Komodo (aka KMD)  Bluetooth ear piece, as headphones. Worked perfectly.

The volume buttons controlled the ear piece, and if I hit one of the volume buttons, the phone says "Bluetooth In-Call Volume (volume bar)".   So... I say try that one out...

Answer (score 0):

lol i remember i have an old moto rizr z3 using stereo headphones, but, by default when you listen to music, it uses mono sound for some reason. There is an option in the options menu to switch to stereo but sorry this is not android and i only have stereo headphones